# Some trouble with "catchError" angular function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable, angular-errorhandler

I had an error

[this is an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kkBr.png)

So I am learning how to catch errors with the catchError function in angular htttp services
I have a ts file that executes function handler errors

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})export class ProcessHttpMsgService {

constructor() { }

public handelError(error: HttpErrorResponse| any){let errMsg: string;

if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  errMsg = error.error.message;
} else {
  errMsg =`${error.status}- ${error.statusText || ''} ${error.error}`
}

return  new Error(errMsg)

}}
```

And I have a service that uses this function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from "../shared/dish";
import {catchError, Observable, scheduled} from 'rxjs'import { map } from "rxjs";import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { baseURL } from "../shared/baseurl";
import {ProcessHttpMsgService} from "./process-http-msg.service";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DishService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient,
private processHttpMsgService:ProcessHttpMsgService){
}

getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]>{return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes').pipe(catchError(this.processHttpMsgService))}

getDish(id: string): Observable<Dish>{return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL + 'dishes/' + id)}

getFeaturedDish():Observable<Dish>{return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL +  'dishes?featured=true').pipe(map(dishes => dishes[0]))}

getDishIds(): Observable<number[] | any>{return this.getDishes().pipe(map(dishes => dishes.map(dish => dish.id)))}
}
```

Comment: You probably didn't intend to create that many code snippets, did you? If not, you'll find the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to pass an service class to `catchError`. `catchError` expects you to pass it a function. That function is then supposed to either throw a new `Error`, or return an `Observable`.

Something like:

```
getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]> {
  return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes').pipe(
    catchError((error => {
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        errMsg = error.error.message;
      } else {
        errMsg = `${error.status}- ${error.statusText || ''} ${error.error}`
      }

      throw new Error(errMsg)
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: It's worked for me thank u, but in my task I need to do something like (this.processHttpMsgService.handleError) that to use my handleError in another ts file

Comment: and I had a new error "Argument of type '(error: any) => Error' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Dish[]>) => ObservableInput<any>'.   Type 'Error' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'."

Answer (score 0):

Two small mistakes here:

---

First, [`catchError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) expects a function, not an object. RxJS is used heavily in Angular, but it's not part of angular. It's a standalone library. Important not to confuse the two.

So, if `catchError` expects a function and you want to call `ProcessHttpMsgService.handleError`, you can do this:

```
.pipe(catchError(e => this.processHttpMsgService.handleError(e)));
```

---

Secondly the reference (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) describes `catchError` as follows (emphasis mine):

> Catches errors on the observable to be handled by **returning** a new observable or **throwing** an error.

`return new Error(errMsg);` will return an instance of `Error`, which is neither of the two options.

You either have to

a) return an `Observable`, for example [`throwError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError):

```
public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
  ...

  return throwError(() => new Error(errMsg));
}
```

or b) throw an `Error` using the `throw` statement. In that case you also have to tell RxJS that your function will throw and never return. Set the return type explicitly to `never`:

```
//                                                 VVVVV
public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse| any): never {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I completely and precisely understood how it works!